# Change default error style of DataGridTextColumn cell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a application made in WPF MVVM in which
I'm trying to make the whole row go red instead of just the cell with the error.

```
<DataGrid>
<etc...>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="xx" Width="200" IsReadOnly="False">
  <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <Binding Path="xx">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <v:xxValidator />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
<etc...>
</DataGrid>
```

Right now, this only put a border on the cell with the error and had a "!" at the far left of the row.

I tried to only change the cell background to red with the following code but the `Validation.HasError` is never true.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

In a perfect world, I would like to be able to override the error style so that the whole row has the background red.
I looked around and couldn't find an explanation to do it with a `DataGridTextColumn`.

Comment: Still haven't found the answer by myself. Anyone might know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My code works if I use my validationrule with a textbox but not with a DataGridTextColumn